# Can't connect using (local) on SQL SMS 16.5.1

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Can't connect. i get the same error everytime
[image]

Comment: Before posting is better to read documentations. See the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143219.aspx) and [Stackoverflow help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on particular [don't ask section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You have to restart the SQL services.

1. Go to Run and type `services.msc`

[image]

2. Hit Enter and the services window will open.
3. Find and start all the SQL services.

[image]

**Note:** Before doing this make sure the server is up and running.If not, that's the problem. You will have to turn on the server. If your server on or you are using the local machine as server, follow the above steps.

Comment: SQL Server VSS Writer is the only one with an SQL tag that I have in services.msc

Comment: @BenihimeLolomo Sort it by name and checking the entire list. You should find SQL Agent and SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry I'm a real newbie with this. How do I turn it on? I just installed it a few minutes ago. I am using SSMS 16.5.1

Comment: @BenihimeLolomo I have added the screenshot, go the SQL service.. right click and then start.

Comment: I sorted it by name but only SQL Server VSS Writer exists. No other service with SQL in it's name exists